# Installer Custom action not working

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am trying to remove some additional files under the user profile Local Application Data folder after the uninstall of the app.

i read about custom action, so i wrote this

```
namespace RemoveUserAppDataCA
{
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class Installer1 : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public Installer1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
        // Very important! Removes all those nasty temp files.
        DeleteUserDataProfile();

        base.Dispose(); 
    }

    void DeleteUserDataProfile()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "..\\MyCompanyFolder"));

            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.Delete(path,true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {              
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

}

I added the dll file to the project setup , then a added a custom actions , then under the uninstall , i added the ddl file of the  RemoveUserAppDataCA . i built the system.

i did the installation , but when i uninstall the app the app folderthe user profile Local Application Data remains (does not get deleted).

What is wrong about the work ??

Comment: `try..catch...throw` is something that looks weird to me...

Comment: As @UweKeim hints - remove the throw or set a breakpoint to see the Exception you are likely getting.

Comment: If the folder is under the Local Application Data folder then why do you have .. in your path?  That would make it look in a sibling instead of a child folder.  Also, you cannot generally assume that the user account executing the uninstaller is the same user account that is normally used to execute the program.  In other words the data you want to delete might be in a totally different user profile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem , the folder path was wrong. The system was pointing at
 **"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\App_Folder"** instead of **"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\App_Folder"**